# Parallelism of as...as

Tags: grammar, word-usage, comparisons, parallelism

For these two sentences, why do we need to use "he was" and "it is"? What two things are being compared in these sentences?

> Henry was almost as famous a philosopher as **he was** a poet.
>
> It is as important to purchase fresh herbs as **it is** to use techniques
>   recommended in the cookbook.

Also, I wonder if we can **delete** "he was" and "it is" and the grammar is still correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two examples are simply comparing two adjectives of the same subject. A general structure of sentences like these would look something like this:

*Subject* + *adjective*

as

*subject* + *another adjective*.

The 'he was' phrase is simply denoting which subject the second adjective is referring to. If the subjects were different then the sentence could look like, *'Henry was almost as famous a philosopher as Richard was a poet'*.

Therefore, to answer your question, the grammar of the sentences wouldn't be correct if you remove the bolded words.